# Entity Framework returns faulty data while querying

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

If i run the following

```
  var allrecords = proxy.itemAuditReports.ToList().OrderBy(u=>u.SKU);
```

i get this in allrecords.

- [0]= Inventory=60, Usage = 20, Month =1 , Sku=001

  [1]= Inventory=60, Usage =20, Month =1, Sku=001

But in the db i have values for

- Month 1: Inventory =60, Usage=20, SKU:001

  Month 4: Inventory = 20, Usage =10, SKU 001

What is going wrong here ???

Comment: One line of code is not sufficient to diagnose a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess with only one line of code, is that what EF thinks is your primary key, is in fact not unique.

Comment: Yeah figured that out just a minute ago. THanks anyhow !!